# Get Integer[] instead of ArrayList<Integer> from YAML file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, yaml, snakeyaml

I am parsing a YAML file

```
Props:
  Prop1 : [10, 22, 20]
  Prop2 : [20, 42, 60]
```

This gives me `Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>`
I would like to get `Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>>`
I do not want to convert `List<Integer> to Integer[]` in the code that reads the file. Can I change something in my YAML file?

Comment: No. "12 more to go..."

Comment: @StephanBijzitter can you elaborate?

Comment: Whether you get a List or an array is a decision made by the library that parses the YAML, and is not a feature of the YAML document itself.

Comment: I am using snakeYaml, does this lib provide custom configuration? Does any other lib provide custom configuration of types it returns?

Comment: Show us how you do your deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to my other answer, this one focuses on changing the YAML file. However, you also need to add some Java code to tell SnakeYaml how to load the tag you use.

You could add tags to the YAML sequences:

```
Props:
  Prop1 : !intarr [10, 22, 20]
  Prop2 : !intarr [20, 42, 60]
```

This need to be registered with SnakeYaml before loading:

```
public class MyConstructor extends Constructor {
    public MyConstructor() {
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!intarr"),
                                  new ConstructIntegerArray());
    }

    private class ConstructIntegerArray extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            final List<Object> raw = constructSequence(node);
            final Integer[] result = new Integer[raw.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < raw.size(); i++) {
                result[i] = (Integer) raw.get(i);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new MyConstructor());
Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>> content =
    (Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>>) yaml.load(myInput);
```

Comment: I am trying to use
<code>
yamlClassConstructors.put(NodeId.sequence, new AbstractConstruct() {
    @Override
    public Integer[] construct(Node node) {
      List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) constructSequence((SequenceNode)node);
      return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
    }
  };);
<code>
instead of custom tag. But it returns ArrayList, probably never gets used.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try to debug it to check whether it's called? This method is described [here](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Howto) so it should work.

Comment: Try to inherit from `ConstructSequence` instead of `AbstractConstruct` and override [construct2ndStep](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/f437efd6719eaa93d616c7aca164a3d2d07f0031/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java?at=default#Constructor.java-645) similar to the Howto.

Comment: `construct(Node node)` was never called!

Comment: `useClassConstructor` in `Node` returns false!

Answer (score 1):

From the snakeyaml documentation:

```
Default implementations of collections are:

 - List: ArrayList 
 - Map: LinkedHashMap (the order is implicitly defined)
```

There is no easy way to change it. Just call `toArray()` on a list and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout of your YAML file is stable, you can map it directly to a Java class, which defines the types of the inner properties:

```java
public class Props {
    public Integer[] prop1;
    public Integer[] prop2;
}

public class YamlFile {
    public Props props;
}
```

Then, you can load it like this:

```java
final Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(YamlFile.class));
final YamlFile content = (YamlFile) yaml.load(myInput);
// do something with content.props.prop1, which is an Integer[]
```

I used standard Java naming for the properties, which would require you to change the keys in your YAML file to lower case:

```
props:
  prop1 : [10, 22, 20]
  prop2 : [20, 42, 60]
```

You can also keep the upper case, but you'd need to rename the Java properties accordingly.

Comment: I like the approach but my YAML file is not stable, a prop can be array other can be int, double etc.