# Read Integer List from yaml file

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

The current implementation is :-

```
public static final List<Integer> validCodes = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(110, 210, 310,510,610));
```

However, I am not happy with this approach as this of hard coded. I want to make it configurable instead of hard-coded. I suppose reading this values from the yaml file would solve my problem.

But how do I define a list of Integer in the yaml file and real it using @value. I can find a lot of example about reading list of strings but not integers.

Comment: This too can do `int[] arr = (int[]) Yaml.load(new File("file.yml"));`

Comment: I don't want to read it from a file as well. I want to make it as a configurable property in the yaml file @Vebbie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Integer\[\] instead of ArrayList<Integer> from YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685167/get-integer-instead-of-arraylistinteger-from-yaml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `application.yml` file, define the config variable as follows.

`my_integers: 1231,12323,12321`

then use the `@Value` annotation to make to an Integer list as follows.

```
@Value("#{'${my_integers}'.split(',')}")
private List<Integer> myIntegers;
```

Spring does the rest. You only need to use `myIntegers` with your need. 
Happy coding....

PS: I have used `spring boot 2.0.*`

Answer (score 0):

**One way:**

Let's say if the properties file contains

`intArr={1,2,3}`

Then `@Value` can be used like:

```
@Value("#{${intArr}}")
Integer[] intArr;
```

**Second way:**

If the property contains comma separated values as:
`intArr: [1, 2, 3]`

Then the annotation code would be:

```
@Value("${intArr}")
private int[] intArr;
```

**Edit:**

You can configure `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` which activates the new configuration service which supports converting String to Collection types.

By activating this, it will support following kind of conversion:

```
 intArray= 1, 2, 3, 4
```

And the following code:

```
@Value("${intArray}")
private List<Integer> myList;
```

Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)

Comment: I tried the second way:-
    intArr: [1, 2, 3]

@Value("${intArr}")
private List<Integer> intArr;

Not working!!

Comment: Have you declared any prefix to append before `intArr` in yaml properties ?

Comment: Nope, no prefix. It's giving a null value @Vebbie

Comment: Okay. Editing answer with one more approach.

Comment: Sorry, I was using a static variable. It was the reason for null value. However, the approach doesn't work even for a non-static variable. It says cannot resolve the placeholder. however, If i give it as intArr: '1,2,3' , its working. I guess '[]' bracket is creating issues. However if I use  intArr: '1,2,3' , It becomes a list of String, but I want list of Integer

Comment: In that case you can convert `List<String>` to `List<Integer>` like this: `for(String s : strList) intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189680/discussion-between-vebbie-and-boy).

Answer (score 0):

You can used following method for getting all available properties from YML file. When you used following method, you have to add following jar into your build script.

```
compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.12'
```

I think this will help you to continue your task.

```
private Map<String, Object> loadYMLData() {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            String fileName = "{{YAMAL FILE NAME}}.yml";
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
            InputStream ios = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Parse the YAML file and return the output as a series of Maps and Lists
            result = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(ios);
            System.out.println(result.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error==>", e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```